# ListView в LinearLayout отображает только один элемент списка

Tags: java, android, listview, android-linearlayout

Я использую xml парсер для вывода информации в ListView, xml код

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Этим кодом я добавляю в лист объекты парсера

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
                URL input = new URL("news.xml");
                parser.setInput(input.openStream(), null);
                while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("contact"))
                    {
                        list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + "\n" + "\n"
                                + parser.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n");
                    }
                    parser.next();
                }
```

При простейщем тесте все объекты на месте, но в данном случае показывается только один.  На сколько я понимаю - при каждом добавлении объекта нужно создавать новый LinearLayout вместе с виджетом и списком? не могу понять, как это сделать

Comment: проббовал сделать так `newsPlace.addView(new ListView(parser.next());` но ругается на парсер некст

Comment: list - это у вас что? если массив данных, привязанных через адаптер, обновляйте адаптер - `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, если вдруг нет - делайте через массив и адаптер

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл указать. да это массив и адаптер  `lvInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`  и адаптер  `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvInfo.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Народ, очень прошу помочь

Comment: адаптер обновляете? не вижу этого в коде

Comment: добавил Ваш код после адаптера, толку нет. если я использую только листвью то все работает, а листвью на данный момент находится у меня в кардвью, из за этого показывается только одна новость а не список

Comment: Нужно создавать новый кардвью видимо и в него сувать новость кодом parser.next(); ? все перепробовал

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. добавил этому элементу  `NestedScrollView`  аттрибут  `fillViewport="true"`, теперь все отображается корректно, и все новости работают

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, то опишите решение подробно.

Answer (score 1):

У вас у `CardView` высота по высоте содержимого. А она равна высоте одного элемента списка. Так что замените

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

на

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло( по прежнему выводит 1 элемент новостей

Comment: накопал в интернете, что нельзя ставить листвью в NestedScrollView....  помогло, удалил элемент, но теперь разметка работает некорректно(

Comment: @МаксФадеев, ну, мы бы вам это сразу сказали, если б вы об этом упомянули)